# Gitlab CI/CD through SSH causing error and unable to SSH into aws-ec2-linux server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab, cicd

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-216-48-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [10.0.15.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Rifter-Test-Server.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Rifter-Test-Server.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-216-48-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:KCe1X9MVFUImH5H9q8EkV2VLJ3bSehsJbSLnlWiMM+o
debug1: Host 'ec2-18-216-48-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:29
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:994)
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:994)
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: Rifter-Test-Server.pem
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

while my gitlab yaml config's are as follows

deploy:
stage: deploy
before_script:

- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh
- echo -e “$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY” > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- ssh-keyscan $EC2_IPADDRESS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh/*
  tags:
- node
  script:
  - ssh -Tv -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa" ec2-user@ec2-18-216-48-255.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com "ll; whoami"

Tried several options for login from gitlab CI/CD to aws-ec2-linux but unable till yet if anyone can see the SSH logs and help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the contents of the keyfile are as expected? And that the ssh key is not password protected?

Comment: Yep, you are right I checked the content of the key file after this post that is in one-line instead of being in a format required for SSH, I tried a number of methods for making its format correct while getting the value from variables but it's not working. Any suggestion on it?

Comment: Use file-based variables or encode as base64 first (which can safely be in one line) then decode from base64 -> key text in the pipeline.

Comment: If you can share any example of it our share how can we do this?